# Exceptional cases of conversion in halacha

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, mishna, egypt

Pregnant Egyptian mother who converts to Judaism, what status does the child have at birth?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a woman converts to Judaism while pregnant, will her child be a Jew?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/if-a-woman-converts-to-judaism-while-pregnant-will-her-child-be-a-jew)

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yehuda and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 4):

The son of an Egyptian woman who converts while pregnant with him counts as a second generation Egyptian-convert (Yevamot 78a, Rambam IB 12:20, EH 4:4). Only his children will be able to marry full status Jews (cf. Deuteronomy 23:9). [It is disputed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/125870/759) if this prohibition still applies to modern Egyptians.

Answer (score -2):

Jewish. And all those laws about Egyptians,moabites, ammonites not entering the community or only after x generations only apply to men.

Comment: This is not correct. Only for Moabites and Ammonites does it apply only to men.

Comment: @Clint remember to cite sources when you bring answers, otherwise no one knows how correct you are

Comment: So how could shlomo marry pharoah's daughter

Comment: @ClintEastwood See Yevamot 76

Comment: Ive read the gemara. I didn't realize that you are allowed to have sex with these women as long as you don't legally marry them. I'm going to log off and go do that now.

Comment: Actually, another opinion on the page says they are permitted.